# Gradle task for invoking build tools from the project

Tags: gradle

I have a project that uses gradle as the build tool. As part of the source code for the project there is a tool that generates config files needed for this application. The config generator tool is a Java class with a main method so that it can be run from Java or from the command line.

I want to add a gradle task that invokes the config generator after it has been compiled and jar'ed.

- What's the recommended gradle way of invoking build tools that are part of the project?
- In my gradle task how do I setup the classpath so that the config generator can be invoked with the project dependencies on the classpath and not just the classpath for the gradle JVM?

Comment: You can use JavaExec to invoke any arbitrary java code. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the gradle task that I used to execute my config tool and write the standard out to a file:

```
task generateConfig(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn jar
    main = 'com.example.ConfigGeneratorMain'
    classpath configurations.runtime, jar.archivePath
    doFirst {
        def outputFile = new File(project.buildDir, 'resources/generated/config.json')
        outputFile.mkdirs()
        outputFile.delete()
        outputFile.createNewFile()
        standardOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)
    }
}
assemble.dependsOn generateConfig
```